# Como comparar String com String recebida em um .jsp?

Tags: java, html, string, jsp

Tenho uma pagina html e ela manda um formulário com método tipo POST, pego os dados assim:

```
String email =  request.getParameter("user");
```

Quando comparo a string email com outra string contendo o mesmo texto ele me volta falso. 
Pq isso acontece ? como posso resolver ?

Estou fazendo a comparação normal

```
if(email == "exemplo@email.com"){
    out.println("executou aqui");
}
```

No caso "exemplo@email.com" seria o mesmo valor da String que peguei no método post.

Comment: Como você está comparando?

Comment: Como você está fazendo a comparação?

Comment: if(email == "meu@email.com"){
    out.println("executou aqui");
}

Este texto é o mesmo que estou mandando de outra pagina via POST

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quando você usa ==, você testa se dois objetos são idênticos, olha o exemplo:

```
String texto1 = "Mundo genial";
String texto2 = "Mundo genial";
```

No caso acima se você comparar com == você vai receber o valor desejado, mas como você esta trazendo essa informação, é o mesmo que fazer isso:

```
String s1 = new String("Mundo genial");
String s2 = new String("Mundo genial");
```

Nesse caso você está comparando conteúdo e a comparação tem que ser feita com equals,

```
boolean comparar = s1.equals(s2); // resultado = true
boolean comparar = s1 == s2; // resultado = false
```

Caso você queira continuar com o == você teria que de alguma forma apontar pro mesmo objeto, algo tipo assim:

```
String s1 = new String("Mundo genial");
String s2 = s1;
```

No caso acima se você fizer a comparação s1 == s2, o valor seria verdadeiro, pois eles estão apontando para o mesmo objeto.